# ERROR: No matching distribution found for rlsa

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

i was trying to install RLSA using  pip install pythonRLSA

but i got the  ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rlsa (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rlsa

Does anyone know how I could solve this error?

Comment: Also I retrying the installation with " pip install rlsa-python" i got  Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./myEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from rlsa-python) (1.21.0) but when i run my code i got Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo2.py", line 68, in <module>
    from rlsa import RLSA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rlsa'

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1. `rlsa` is a module in the `pythonRLSA` package, so it must be imported as such.
2. The `rlsa` function you are trying to use is called `rlsa`, not `RLSA`.
   Any of the following code snippets will work (tested on Python 3.7.9):

```
import pythonRLSA
pythonRLSA.rlsa.rlsa(...)
```

```
import pythonRLSA.rlsa as rlsa
rlsa.rlsa(...)
```

```
from pythonRLSA.rlsa import rlsa
rlsa(...)
```